# Is this possible to change existing xhtml dita ot plugin as customised plugin

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

Is this possible to change the existing base DITA OT XHTML plugin as customized plugin

If possible means please give me guide lines

As required name of the plugin is com.process.xhtml

and trans type should be xhtml-ver-5

after that what are the changes needed in side the plugin to run the dita ot transformation successfully

I have tried like this

I have changed the plugin name as com.process.xhtml and replaced the files inside the plugin in place of org.dita.xhtml with com.process.xhtml this one.

After that transformation xhtml-ver-5 running  I am getting error as

```
Engine name: DITA-OT
Severity: error
Description: Target "dita2xhtml-ver-5" does not exist in the project "DOST".
```

Please give me the guidelines for changing the existing base DITA OT XHTML plugin as customized plugin

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DITA OT documentation there is a section about building custom HTML plugins:

http://www.dita-ot.org/dev/dev_ref/html-customization-plugins.html

After you build the plugin you also need to run the DITA OT integrator to integrate it by running this command:

```
 dita -install
```

Comment: I want to change base plugin in side the DITA OT 1.8.5 named as org.dita.xhtml to my custom plugin named com.process.xhtml for that any procedure or guidelines is there means please provide me Thanks for your answer its helped me partially

Comment: If the answer was helpful, then you could cast a vote up ;).

Comment: Hi @Radu Coravu can you provide me any html2 customized plugin

Comment: You should first try to create it yourself, and if you have specific questions, then you can ask them.

Comment: Hi @Radu Coravu I have tried to create the xhtml custom plugin but its converting the topics file which was generated by transformation but its applying to index.html in   plugin.xml i have added the as feature extension=dita.xsl.xhtml file=xsl/dita2xhtml.xsl so its converting topics then for index.html i have to change for that what changes i can do please suggest me

Comment: I'm linking to the new topic you posted about this, I will try to find some time to look into it, maybe give you some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360542/custom-xhtml-plugin-creation-index-html-not-effecting